# How can I remove the header "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive" from a php CURL request?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm am trying to access a webpage using an HTTP proxy with curl and php. I want to make the request look as close as possible to a real browser, however when I send the GET request through CURL, it sends the header "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive" even when I haven't specified it. How can I remove "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive" from the sent headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `-H` parameter without specifying a value for the internal headers you want to remove:

```
curl -H "Proxy-Connection:" http://somehost
```

Comment: I'm not using curl via command, however this also worked in php. I just set the parameter in the header array without specifying the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using recent version of curl, you [should use](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/2481#issuecomment-380389539) `--proxy-header` option:

```
curl --proxy-header "Proxy-Connection:" http://somehost
```

This is `CURLOPT_PROXYHEADER` option in php which available starting from php 7.0.7.